# I want to do image processing with gdal and ubuntu shell script

Tags: shell, loops, raster, gdal

[Code is here...]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgoW8.png
I want to image processing with gdal and shell script, Multiple raster image

```
pan=$(ls *-PAN.tiff)
mux=$(ls *-MUX.tiff)
for i in *.tiff
do
 if ["$i" == "$pan"] || ["$i" == "$mux"]
 then  #echo '$pan'
       #echo '$mux'
       gdalwarp -wo "SAMPLE_GRID=NO" -et 0 -rpc -to RPC_DEM=./DEM_30M.tif  $mux ortho_$mux
       gdalwarp -wo "SAMPLE_GRID=NO" -et 0 -rpc -to RPC_DEM=./DEM_30M.tif  $pan ortho_$pan
       gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:4326"  -dstalpha ortho_$pan of_$pan
       echo 'of_$pan'
       gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:4326"  -dstalpha ortho_$mux of_$mux
       echo 'of_$mux'
       gdal_pansharpen.py  -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 of_$pan of_$mux pansharpened_$pan
       gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:4326"  -dstnodata 0 -dstalpha -of Gtiff pansharpened_$pan nob_pansharpened_$pan
 else
       echo 'Not similiar'
 fi
done
```

Comment: Please format your code properly by clicking `edit`, then selecting your code with the mouse and clicking `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic*.

Comment: What is your actual question please?

Comment: Try pasting your code into http://shellcheck.net

Comment: No, please do not post pictures of your code - we cannot run it, search it, test it, change it. What is your question please?

Comment: If your *"question"* is "I want to do image processing", it will get closed because the answer is going to be something like *"Good, feel free to go ahead and do it".*

Comment: @MarkSetchell , yes i want.  Can you help me?

Comment: I would like to try, but first you need to 1) share your code properly 2) clearly state your question. Until then I don't know if I can help.

Comment: I copied my code above. How could I process multiple scenes by using GDAL and Ubuntu Shell script?

Comment: Ok, copy your code and paste it into http://shellcheck.net and it will tell you the error(s).